# Recursive use of typeclass methods in Coq

Tags: coq, typeclass

Is there a way to use recursion with Coq's typeclasses? Like for e.g., in defining show for lists, if you want to call the `show` function for lists recursively, then you will have to use a fixpoint like so:

```
Require Import Strings.String.
Require Import Strings.Ascii.

Local Open Scope string_scope.


Class Show (A : Type) : Type :=
  {
    show : A -> string
  }.


Section showNormal.

Instance showList {A : Type} `{Show A} : Show (list A) :=
  {
    show :=
      fix lshow l :=
        match l with
        | nil => "[]"
        | x :: xs => show x ++ " : " ++ lshow xs
        end
  }.

End showNormal.
```

Which is all well and good, but what if I want to define some helper function that I'll use for defining `Show` instances? Like I want to create a more DAZZLING show function called `magicShow` that prints stars around something...

```
Definition magicShow {A : Type} `{Show A} (a : A) : string :=
  "** " ++ show a ++ " **".


Instance showMagicList {A : Type} `{Show A} : Show (list A) :=
  {
    show :=
      fix lshow l :=
        match l with
        | nil => "[]"
        | x :: xs => show x ++ " : " ++ magicShow xs
        end
  }.
```

However, in this case Coq can't find a show instance for the list `xs` to pass to `magicShow`:

```
Error:
Unable to satisfy the following constraints:
In environment:
A : Type
H : Show A
lshow : list A -> string
l : list A
x : A
xs : list A

?H : "Show (list A)"
```

Is there any way to do this in general? I.e., can you define a method for a typeclass using functions that rely upon the typeclass instance that you're defining?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this.  This works in Haskell because arbitrary recursive bindings are allowed, and the language doesn't care about the order of bindings.  Coq is more restrictive on both fronts.  This makes sense if you think about what the desugaring looks like: the recursive call to `show` would refer to the currently-being-defined instance by name, but that binding isn't in scope yet.  And you can't make the instance itself a fixpoint because you're recursing on the structure of a *type*, not on a value of an algebraic data type.

Your inline fixpoint works for `show`, but the problem gets thornier if your method implementations refer to each other, such as

```hs
newtype MyInteger = MyInteger Integer

instance Num MyInteger where
  MyInteger m + MyInteger n = MyInteger $ m  + n
  negate (MyInteger m) = MyInteger $ negate m
  m - n = m + negate n
  -- other methods
```

Here, the calls to `(+)` and `negate` in the definition of `(-)` needs to refer to the definitions of `(+)` and `negate` above, but this also doesn't work in Coq.  The only solution is to define all your methods separately, manually referencing each other, and then define the instance simply by setting each method to the one you defined above.  For example,

```
Inductive MyInteger := Mk_MyInteger : Integer -> MyInteger.

Definition add__MyInteger (m n : MyInteger) : MyInteger :=
  let 'Mk_MyInteger m' := m in
  let 'Mk_MyInteger n' := n in
  Mk_MyInteger (add m' n').

Definition negate__MyInteger (m : MyInteger) : MyInteger :=
  let 'Mk_MyInteger m' := m in
  Mk_MyInteger (negate m').

Definition sub__MyInteger (m n : MyInteger) : MyInteger :=
  add__MyInteger m (negate__MyInteger n).

Instance Num__MyInteger : Num MyInteger := {|
  add    := add__MyInteger;
  negate := negate__MyInteger;
  sub    := sub__MyInteger;
  (* other methods *)
|}.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must do this, it can be simulated by explicitly using the constructor of the underlying `Record` (since "Typeclasses are Records", to quote from Software Foundations [[1](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/qc-current/Typeclasses.html)]), which can be instantiated using the function(s) being defined as a fixpoint. I'll post three examples and explain where this can be useful.

The example you posted could be solved like this (all code tested for Coq 8.10.1):

```
Require Import Strings.String.

Local Open Scope list_scope.
Local Open Scope string_scope.

Class Show (A : Type) : Type :=
  {
    show : A -> string
  }.

Definition magicShow {A : Type} `{Show A} (a : A) : string :=
  "** " ++ show a ++ " **".

Print Show.
(* Record Show (A : Type) : Type := Build_Show { show : A -> string }
*)
Check Build_Show.
(* Build_Show : forall A : Type, (A -> string) -> Show A *)
Check @magicShow.
(* @magicShow : forall A : Type, Show A -> A -> string *)

Instance showMagicList {A : Type} `{Show A} : Show (list A) :=
  {
    show :=
      fix lshow l :=
        match l with
        | nil => "[]"
        | x :: xs => show x ++ " : " ++ @magicShow _ (@Build_Show _ lshow) xs
        end
  }.
```

If you are trying to define several typeclass methods like this, it's tricky to instantiate the record constructor, but it can be done by treating the functions as if they were defined by mutual recursion (although there doesn't necessarily have to be any actual mutual recursion). Here's a contrived example where `Show` now has two methods. Notice that the typeclass instance is added to the context with an anonymous `let-in` binding. Evidently, this is enough to satisfy Coq's typeclass resolution mechanism.

```
Require Import Strings.String.

Local Open Scope list_scope.
Local Open Scope string_scope.

Class Show (A : Type) : Type :=
  {
    show1 : A -> string
  ; show2 : A -> string
  }.

Definition magicShow1 {A : Type} `{Show A} (a : A) : string :=
  "** " ++ show1 a ++ " **".

Definition magicShow2 {A : Type} `{Show A} (a : A) : string :=
  "** " ++ show2 a ++ " **".

Fixpoint show1__list {A : Type} `{Show A} (l : list A) : string :=
let _ := (@Build_Show _ show1__list show2__list) in
        match l with
        | nil => "[]"
        | x :: xs => show1 x ++ " : " ++ magicShow1 xs
        end
with show2__list {A : Type} `{Show A} (l : list A) : string :=
let _ := (@Build_Show _ show1__list show2__list) in
        match l with
        | nil => "[]"
        | x :: xs => show1 x ++ " : " ++ magicShow2 xs
        end.

Instance showMagicList {A : Type} `{Show A} : Show (list A) :=
  {
    show1 := show1__list
  ; show2 := show2__list
  }.
```

So why would you want to do this? A good example is when you are defining decidable equality on (rose) trees. In the middle of the definition, we have to recursively appeal to decidable equality of `list (tree A)`. We would like to use the standard library helper function `Coq.Classes.EquivDec.list_eqdec` [[2](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Classes.EquivDec.html)], which shows how to pass decidable equality on a type `A` to `list A`. Since `list_eqdec`  requires a typeclass instance (the very one we are in the middle of defining), we have to use the same trick above:

```
Require Import Coq.Classes.EquivDec.
Require Import Coq.Program.Utils.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Generalizable Variables A.

Inductive tree (A : Type) : Type :=
  | leaf : A -> tree A
  | node : list (tree A) -> tree A.

Program Instance tree_eqdec `(eqa : EqDec A eq) : EqDec (tree A) eq :=
 { equiv_dec := fix tequiv t1 t2 :=
    let _ := list_eqdec tequiv in
    match t1, t2 with
    | leaf a1, leaf a2 =>
        if a1 == a2 then in_left else in_right
    | node ts1, node ts2 =>
        if ts1 == ts2 then in_left else in_right
    | _, _ => in_right
    end
}.

Solve Obligations with unfold not, equiv, complement in * ;
  program_simpl ; intuition (discriminate || eauto).

Next Obligation.
  destruct t1;
  destruct t2; 
  ( program_simpl || unfold complement, not, equiv in *; eauto ).
Qed.

Solve Obligations with split; (intros; try unfold complement, equiv ; program_simpl).
(*
No more obligations remaining
tree_eqdec is defined
*)
```

Commentary: There is no constructor for creating a record of type `EqDec` (since  it only has one class method), so to convince Coq that `list (tree A)` has decidable equality, the invocation is simply `list_eqdec tequiv`. For the uninitiated, `Program` here is simply allowing for holes in the definition of the instance to be filled in later as `Obligation`s, which is more convenient than writing the appropriate proofs inline.